# Deploying Java Application(Main Class) over Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, program-entry-point

I have a Java Application consisting of a Main Class and Java Proxies(Created using Axis 1.4).There are no Servlets or JSP`s

The program takes i/p from an excel sheet.Queries an internet application using Webservices.This  process continues until all the records in the Excel have been executed.

Now my First question is how do I deploy this application on Weblogic:As a WAR, EAR or JAR(Not as WAR ofcourse)
If it is a web application we can invoke it by a path like

```
http://server:port/contxt_root/abc.jsp
```

but this aint a web application, so how would I invoke it.
In Jdevloper I right Click on Main Class, Click RUN and it starts executing.Now I have to deploy over a Weblogic Server in a Linux System

Second Question: How do I shedule it.Suppose if i want it to run weekly or daily.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you don't need any kind of web related servers, but some kind of a task scheduler, like [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule a [command line starting your Java application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

You can run your compiled classes too, I'd advise to [create a JAR file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) of them, that makes things a lot more clean.

Comment: Do u mean to say then i dont need to deploy this on weblogic...but to run it using some command lines.

Comment: @Sankalp Exactly. On Linux, you can use cron, on Windows, I used Task Scheduler a few times to run the command. Depending on what you need to do, you might want to write a script for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your program a timer EJB:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Just note that Java EE entities don't work to well with local files, so you need to consider where your excel sheet is located.

I'm not so sure you need to make it a Java EE app, just a scheduled program.

Good luck